# CCW copmonent use in javascript gives error Undefined

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, com, ccw

**Interface Implemented Class**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("13FE32AD-4BF8-495f-AB4D-6C61BD463EA4")]//GUID for this class
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]//Donot generage any interface automatically.  We will explicitly create one
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMathInterface))]//Expose events
    [ProgId("CCWTEST.ClassMath")]//Friendly name of the class. Used while creating object without using 'New' keyword
    public class ClassMath : IMathInterface
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        int IMathInterface.Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
```

**Interface**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("D6F88E95-8A27-4ae6-B6DE-0542A0FC7039")]//GUID for this interface
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]//Enable early as well as late binding
    public interface IMathInterface
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        int  Add(int i, int j);
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = onLoad;
        function onLoad()
        {
            try
            {                
                var obj = new ActiveXObject("CCWTEST.ClassMath");           

            }
            catch (e)
            {
                alert(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

I have created windows form class type library.
DLL business logic have to use in Asp.net page.
For that purpose generated an CCW Wrapper class
In Wrapper class create interface for function declaration.
And implement interface function in wrapper class.
Make all function [comvisible=true]

Register the dll in GAC.
Now Have to use in asp.net page So created ActiveXObject. Its giving me exception "undefined"

Comment: Can you remove ClassInterface and ComSourceInterfaces attributes on the class and see if it works any better?

Comment: @Simon I have 15 3rd Party Class library that i have add reference in Com Component Shall i have to register and create .tlb for those dll using regasm on current machine

Comment: done .tlb files of those 15 dll but still not getting ActiveX object

Comment: Just to make sure: do you register your components on the server or on the client? javascript client can only use client-side registered COM objects.

Comment: on the client I m using still only on localhost

Comment: Simon ...Explaining Scenario of my current project if u have any idea then please suggest

Comment: I have created user control of windows form class type library.
User control have other third party dll refrences for some functionality.
That user control have to use in Asp.net page.
For that purpose generated an CCW Wrapper class  
In Wrapper class create interface for function declaration.
And implement interface function in wrapper class.
Make all function [comvisible=true]
Register COM DLL in GAC.
Create .tlb file of COM DLL.
And have created AcivXobject of COM DLL.

Comment: if i register only COM DLL in gac and generate .tlb file then it should work or What u suggest ..\